# How can you get an SD card to work with Android apps on Chromebook?

Tags: android, sd-card, chromebook

I just bought the Samsung Chromebook Plus that came out today, along with a 64gb micro sd card.

There are several problems getting the Chromebook to play nice with Android, but one problem seems like there should be an easy fix.

For some reason, my sd card is only available to the Android side of things, and Android does not have access to format (or see) the SD card, because it's been formatted by Chrome.

So, I can't setup things like Spotify to store music on the card.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

SD Cards are currently not supported for Android apps on Chromebooks. There are promises that they will be in the future.

This [source](https://chromeunboxed.com/android-apps-getting-sd-card-support-on-chromebooks/) refers to the following comment (excerpted here), from a Chromium.org representative:

> Comment 6 by hashimoto@chromium.org, Dec 2
>
> FWIW: You can select multiple files on Chrome OS's "Files" app to open them with an Android app.
>
> Read access of external storage devices for Android apps will come within a few milestones (i.e. 1 quarter or more).
>
> Write access will come after that.

A later update:

> Comment 13 by hashimoto@chromium.org, Feb 13
>
> Sorry, at this moment we are not working on this feature as we have other items more prioritized.
>
> Currently we are planning to work on this feature in M-59 or M-60.
>   I'll keep you updated here.

Answer (score 2):

SD Card support for Android on Chrome (ARC++) is available in ChromeOS (version 62).

From: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660189

Developers will need to update their apps to support the Android Storage Framework.

Technical details at my StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123748/295004

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem on the SD card shouldn't be an issue, especially not if you have "formatted" it with Chrome OS. Typical XY problem.

If you open a shell you will find that the only binary to create filesystems is `mkexfatfs`¹. exFAT should be supported pretty well on "Android" to speak in this terminology. The mount flags also look ok. I found the following bug on the Chromium bugtracker for the new ARC ([ARC++](https://lwn.net/Articles/701964/)?) / (Anroid) App Runtime for Chrome which appears to be related as far as I can tell:

- Issue 660189: [Require USB or SD Card external storage access for Android apps running on the 2016 Chromebook ARC](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660189)

Have a look at comment 13 the latest at the time of writing. Unfortunately I don't have a Chromebook (Flip C302/N22) that currently runs ARC++ in the stable channel to test.

---

1. But you can also mount EXT4 in Chrome OS to no surprise.